# Запрос на проверку наличия таблицы нужной конфигурации в MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Допустим есть бд, в ней таблица с названием нужным нам, и неизвестным строением.

Возможно ли при подключении в бд проверить ее наличие, если она существует (если нет - просто создаем нужную, вопросов нет) - проверить ее строение на предмет соответствия (имеет ли смысл подобное), если не подходит - проще удалить таблицу - DROP и создать с нуля, или удалить содержимое через ALTER и пересоздать?

Как сделать наиболее правильно, не бестолково, и имеет ли тут значение скорость?

UPD. Выбор сделан в пользу DROP - CREATE, без ненужных телодвижений чтобы.
Спасибо @Mike.

Comment: нужно пересоздавать делайте drop и создавайте заново. причем тут скорость совершенно не ясно. Если вы хотите пересоздавать ее раз в секунду то конечно скорость будет иметь значение. но что то мне не приходит в голову система где таблицы могут пересоздаваться так часто. ну а проверять строение или нет - исключительно вам решать, это от задачи зависит. А вообще БД обычно нужна что бы хранить данные и просто так удалять таблицу с данными странное решение. что это за данные такие и зачем они вообще хранятся, если вы готовы в любой момент их удалить.

Comment: P.S. через alter данные удалить нельзя и ваша фраза с ним не имеет никакого смысла. потому что "drop и создать" и "alter и пересоздать" это явно одна и та же операция, потому что пересоздать это именно drop и create и никак иначе

Comment: @Mike это от незнания просто, я мало в этой области еще изучил, спасибо!

Comment: Странный вы выбор все таки сделали. Я вижу только один момент когда это может понадобится - при изменении версии приложения, когда структура таблицы меняется или при повторной инсталляции, когда вы точно знаете, что предыдущие таблицы вам не нужны. А если данные у вас временные - то стоит использовать временные таблицы (temporary table)